# providing int32_t to inet_ntoa causes segFault. why is that

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to convert ip values as hex contained in `uint32_t` data type. So I dont think this is any wrong since inet_ntoa gets `iphdr->saddr and iphdr->daddr` but I get segFault at inet_ntoa function call. gcc warning says

```
warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
92 |                         char *recv = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)
```

this is my code

```
  uint32_t temp =getlastbyte();
  uint32_t *x=(void *)(0xc0a80a02&temp);
  char *recv = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)
                     *x);
```

and when I removed this cast `*(struct in_addr*)` then my code does not compile

any solution to this. please tell

error

```
                          ^
code.c:93:26: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘inet_ntoa’
   93 |                          *x);
      |                          ^~
      |                          |
      |                          uint32_t {aka unsigned int}
```

Comment: Why all this weird-play with `*x` and `void*` casts? Just declare a `struct in_addr` variable, give the `.s_addr` (Linux) or `.S_addr` (Windows) member of that the value, then pass the struct to the function, like what it expects.

Comment: I have to ask ... What do you think this line does, why do you have it: `uint32_t *x=(void *)(0xc0a80a02&temp);` ?

Comment: recv is not a good choice  for a variable name, since it is a common function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype for *inet_ntoa* is `char* inet_ntoa( struct in_addr in )`, with *in_addr* essentially being defined as `struct in_addr { uint32_t s_addr; }`.  *inet_ntoa* converts a network byte order (NBO) IPv4 address to a zero-terminated, dotted-decimal string.  As such, one sets *s_addr* to a 32-bit IPv4 in NBO and passes that the containing *in_addr* object to *inet_ntoa*.

In reference to:

```
 1   uint32_t temp =getlastbyte();
 2   uint32_t *x=(void *)(0xc0a80a02&temp);
 3   char *recv = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)*x);
```

There would seem to be several issues:

- Your second line would seem to be attempting to bitwise-and the 32-bit network byte order (NBO) representation of 192.168.10.2 with the return from `getlastbyte()`.  I'm not sure why you'd want to do this; though, if you're trying to add a network address (e.g., 192.168.10.x) to a host address (e.g., x.x.x.50) to obtain the 32-bit NBO representation of something along the lines of 192.168.10.50, you'd want to bitwise-or (or add) (e.g., `0xC0A80A00 + getlastbyte()`).
- Your second line takes the value `0xC0A80A02 & temp` and attempts to cast it to a `(void*)`, as if it were a valid memory address.  Alternatively, you might want something along the lines of `uint32_t temp = 0xC0A80A00 + getlastbyte(); uint32_t *x = &temp;`, which stores `0xC0A80A00 + getlastbyte()` into `temp` and then obtains a reference to `temp`, storing that address in the pointer `x`.  In short, your second line is establishing a pointer to an invalid address, which is why, when being dereferenced in line 3, a SIGSEGV (segmentation fault) is triggered.
- Your third line is attempting to dereference your invalid pointer and then dereference that.  Continuing the speculated example from the previous bullet, perhaps you might want something along the lines of `char *recv = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)&temp)` or `char *recv = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)x)`.  In short, you generally shouldn't attempt to cast a value to an address or vice versa, unless you truly mean to do so.
- Your example doesn't seem to adequately consider byte-order; i.e., no host-to-network order conversions (e.g., using `htonl`).
- It's generally ill-advised to assume bitwise equivalency for non-structured and structured types.  Otherwise, compile-time data structure alignment issues may present.

In summary, I believe you may want something along the lines of (assuming you're truly trying to add 192.168.10.0 to a last octet or the like):

```
 1   uint32_t ipn = htonl( 0xC0A80A00 + getlastbyte() );
 2   char *ipa = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)&ipn);
```

As a simple example to add the network address 192.168.10.0 to a .20 host address (compiled with `gcc -Wall -o inet_ntoa inet_ntoa.c` and executed as `./inet_ntoa` on a Linux x86_64 host):

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t ip = htonl( 0xC0A80A00 + 0x14 );
    printf("%s\n",inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)&ip));
    return(0);
}
```

When run, this program produces the output:

```
192.168.10.20
```